# WPF: TabControl with multiple DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` with multiple `DataTemplate`. the first `DataTemplate` will be used for search reasons and the second will be for displaying items obtained from that search. My `XAML` code will be as follows:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <!--First template-->
    <DataTemplate>
        <!-- I will have a DataGrid here-->
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Second template-->
    <DataTemplate >
         <!-- I will have details of one item of the DataGrid-->
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>


<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding }"/>
```

What I want to accomplish is that in the `TabControl` the first tab will contain the first `DataTemplate` (the search template) and when I double click on one row of my `DataGrid`, a tab will be added with the details of that row (in other words a tab with the second template).

Since I am using `MVVM`, I thought of creating two `UserControl`s, one for each template and then catch the double click event, but after this I don't know how to add a tab since now my search template is a `UserControl` seperated from the one that contains the `TabControl`.

So how do I do this?

***UPDATE:***

As I read the answers I think I wasn't very clear in stating the problem.
My problem is how to add tabs with the second template, by catching double click events from the first template. I don't have any problem in adding the two templates independently.

Answer (score 2):

Rather can creating two `UserControl`s, you can create and use a `DataTemplateSelector` in order to switch different `DataTemplate`s in.

Basically, create a new class that inhereits from `DataTemplateSelector` and override the `SelecteTemplate` method.  Then declare an instance of it in the XAML (much like a value converter), and then apply it to `ContentTemplateSelector` property of the `TabControl`.

[More info can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do this with MVVM, your tab control should be bound to some `ObservableCollection` in your VM, and you just add and remove VM's to the collection as needed.

The VMs can be any type you like and your DataTemplates will show the correct view in the tab just like any other view, so yes, create two UserControls for the two views.

```
public class MainVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Views { get; private set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        this.Views = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        this.Views.Add(new SearchVM(GotResults));
    }

    private void GotResults(Results results)
    {
        this.Views.Add(new ResultVM(results));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are accessing UI elements (views) from viewmodel what is generally considered as bad practice, because it is violation of "separation of concern" mvvm principle. Ideally, you should access only other viewmodels, model or services in viewmodel layer. In this case, it is very easy to keep the principle and it has significant benefits.

Comment: Nope. I know the collection is called Views but it contains VMs. It is a conceptual View rather than an actual UI view. Could have called it Tabs or something instead. This is a standard MVVM pattern

Comment: In that case, I have no objections :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options: Use datatemplate selector, or use implicit datatemplates and different types for each tabitem.

**1. DataTemplateSelector:**

```
public ObservableCollection<TabItemVM> Tabs { get; private set; }

public MainVM()
{
    Tabs = ObservableCollection<TabItemVM>
    {
        new TabItemVM { Name="Tab 1" },
    };
}

void AddTab(){
   var newTab = new TabItemVM { Name="Tab 2" };
   Tabs.Add(newTab);
   //SelectedTab = newTab; //you may bind TabControl.SelectedItemProperty to viewmodel in order to be able to activate the tab from viewmodel
}

public class TabItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Tab1Template { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Tab2Template { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var tabItem = item as TabItemVM;
        if (tabItem.Name == "Tab 1") return Tab1Template;
        if (tabItem.Name == "Tab 2") return Tab2Template;
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

```
<local:TabItemTemplateSelector
     x:Key="TabItemTemplateSelector"
     Tab1Template="{StaticResource Tab1Template}" 
     Tab2Template="{StaticResource Tab2Template}" />
```

**2. Implicit Data Templates:**

```
public class MainVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabItemVM> Tabs { get; private set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItemVM>
        {
            new Tab1VM(),
        };
    }

    void AddTab()
    {
        var newTab = new Tab2VM()
        Tabs.Add(newTab);
       //SelectedTab = newTab; 
    }
}

public class TabItemBase
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

public class Tab1VM : TabItemBase
{
    public Tab1VM()
    {
        Name = "Tab 1";
    }
}

public class Tab2VM : TabItemBase
{
    public Tab2VM()
    {
        Name = "Tab 2";
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <!--First template-->
   <DataTemplate DataType="local:Tab1VM">
       <!-- I will have a DataGrid here-->
   </DataTemplate>

   <!--Second template-->
   <DataTemplate DataType="local:Tab2VM">
       <!-- I will have details of one item of the DataGrid-->
   </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: I know both of these methods, but this isn't my problem, probably I wasn't very clear. the issue I'm stuck at is that the second template will be added from an event caught from the first template. if the two template were to be added just once at the same time is an easy task.

Comment: In that case change type of Tabs property to `ObservableCollection` . Both approached should work. You may also bind `TabControl.SelectedItem` property to `MainVM.SelectedTab` property, so you can activate newly created tab from your viewmodel