# Bind a TabItem Template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding

I have a TabControl, with a list of TabItems inside, and I want to use different templates regarding the source.
Let's say that 2 TabItems will bind to an object , and 2 TabItes may bind to an ObservableCollection.

For this, I made the following :

I created these ressources :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateType1" >
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColor}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Margin="10,10,20,10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton Visibility="{Binding BottomChoice, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                    Content="True option"
                    GroupName="radioGroup1"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Bottom,
                                        Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolRadioConverter}}" />
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding BottomChoice, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                    Content="False option"
                    GroupName="radioGroup1"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Bottom}" />
                </Grid>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="200">
                    <Image Source="..\img\image_about.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Delete}" Click="DeleteMacro_Click" Margin="3" >
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Change}" Grid.Column="2" Click="EditMacroLeft_Click" Margin="3">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="{x:Static p:Resources.Add}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="20,10,10,10" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then my TabItem like that :

```
<TabItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Type1_Right}" Style="{StaticResource VerticalTabItem}">
    <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="{Binding MacroRight}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateType1}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
</TabItem>
```

I am trying to make my template bind on `MacroRight`, but no binding is working.

Also seen on that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792067/wpf-tabcontrol-with-multiple-datatemplates) that there is a `DataTemplateSelector` possibility, but I see no concrete examples on how to use it?

Comment: did you try to bind Content: `ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MacroRight}" `?

Comment: @Ash just tried to replace `ContentSource` by `Content`, but didn't change anything. precision : Make DataTemplates is new for me, so I am not sure I do it the correct way? I see there are also ControlTemplates, so may I use that instead of DataTemplate (as I will have 2 different Templates)

Comment: DataTemplate is fine. Do you set TabItem.Content?

Comment: you mean on the `<TabItem...` line? I didn't, but just tested to add `Content="{Binding MacroLeft}"` TabItem, but still nothing. And why may I define it twice? (on TabItem + on ContentPresenter)?

Comment: @ASh another idea? In the worst case I will do without Templates (they repeat only twice), but would be good to master them too, as all XAML staff is a bit my weak point ^^'

Comment: @Ash you were right about the first `ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MacroRight}"`, there was something else wrong with my binding. It took time, but on the end to find out, I made a Template without "transfering the binding source" (in Template wrote `MyItem.Name` instead of just `Name`, and until all worked like that, removed all the `MyItem.`, and tried again with your solution. Thanks, if you jus could just put an Answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for [ContentSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contentsource) says:

> This property should only be used when the ContentPresenter is in a template. When a template contains a ContentPresenter with ContentSource set to "Abc", the Content, ContentTemplate, and ContentTemplateSelector properties of the ContentPresenter are automatically aliased to Abc, AbcTemplate, and AbcTemplateSelector, respectively

You should set it as constant (not bind) and let it create Content binding:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="MacroRight" ...
```

or bind [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.content) property yourself, which seems simpler for understanding without downsides:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MacroRight}" ...
```